# How to init a second stream depending on events from the first stream?

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

In my BLOC I need to listen to `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` and depending on users `uid` will init second stream `Firestore.instance.collection('accounts/${uid}/private').snapshots()` and combine results to one model:

```dart
    class MyPageModel {
      bool userSignedIn;
      List<String> privateData;
    }
```

This model need to be streamed out with BehaviorSubject. What is best approach using rxdart for this task?

Comment: From your BLoC you want to expose only a Stream of MyPageModel? Or do you want to expose the auth state as well?

Comment: Only MyPageModel. In case user not logged in set userSignedIn to false, in other case userSignedIn = true and privateData filled

Comment: See if this helps https://gist.github.com/luksprog/67d85ca5cf9bd9f35d08ffa134967f74

Comment: Thanks, Work just fine. Could you please make your comment as reply. I will check it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code below to see how you may combine the two conditional streams:

```
class TheBLoC{
  BehaviorSubject<MyPageModel> _userDataSubject = BehaviorSubject<MyPageModel>();
  // use this in your StreamBuilder widget
  Stream<MyPageModel> get userData => _userDataSubject.stream;
  // a reference to the stream of the user's private data
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> _subscription;
  // bool with the state of the user so we make sure we don't show any data 
  // unless the user is currently loggedin.
  bool isUserLoggedIn;

  TheBLoC() {
    isUserLoggedIn = false;
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser.isAnonymous()) {
        isUserLoggedIn = false;
        final event = MyPageModel();
        event.isSignedIn = false;
        _userDataSubject.add(event);
        // cancel the previous _subscription if available
        _subscription?.cancel();
        // should also probably nullify the _subscription reference 
      } else {
        isUserLoggedIn = true;
        // the user is logged in so acces his's data
        _subscription = Firestore.instance.collection
          ('accounts/${firebaseUser.uid}/private')
            .snapshots().listen((querySnapshots){              
              if(!isUserLoggedIn) return;
              final event = MyPageModel();              
              event.isSignedIn = true;
              // use the querySnapshots to initialize the privateData in 
              // MyPageModel
              _userDataSubject.add(event);
        });
      }
    });
  }

}
```